# Hosting images on the same server as a webpage or using a CDN: What is more efficient/loads faster?

Tags: html, performance, webserver, web-hosting, cdn

I am building my own website and one of the sections on the website will be a section displaying different digital art pieces I have made. This leads me to a curious question, should I host the images on the same server as my website or use a separate CDN to host them and just link to them? What would load better for the user? Will one provide better performance over the other?

This is coming from an efficiency perspective. I know there can be issues with using a separate CDN, or image host, with regards to TOS, relying on a third party host, etc. My question relates to if there would be any significant improvement on the users end by using an external CDN instead of just hosting the images on the same server. I want to display about a dozen images or so on one page, and I know a browser has a limit to how many things it can load at once. Would using a CDN help the browser load the images faster than just normal hosting, or at the very least, load more things at once?

(Note: I'm also using the Materialize framework with the website, although that shouldn't have any effect on how the images are hosted or loaded.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should host images on your own server **and** serve them via CDN

Comment: Hmm, can you expand on how to do this? Should the image tags main src pull from the CDN and the alt pull from the local server? Would it look something like this:`<img src="CDN" alt="localhost" />`, or something like that? Sorry if I sound like a newb. I'm rather new to the backend workings of web programming.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the alt tag, I meant a second src tag.

Comment: @hsoJ95 sign up to CloudFlare or something, point your Name Servers to CF ones and here you go: `<img src="yourdomain.com/image.jpg" />` is served via CloudFlare CDN